# Crashlytics with Visual Studio / Xamarin iOS

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, crashlytics

I'm writing an iOS app with Visual Studio for Mac (not Xamarin Studio) and wanted to integrate Crashlytics.

I created a new Xcode project, made sure the bundle identifiers matched, and ran Crashlytics from the desktop. It said it's good to go, and then I imported Monotouch.Crashlytics into my Visual Studio project, and invoked:

```
string apikey = "<mykey>";      
MonoTouch.Fabric.Crashlytics.Crashlytics.StartWithAPIKey(apikey);
```

after this, it seems to have worked but when I caused a crash nothing got registered.

Does anyone have any ideas /  experience with getting it running?

In visual studio, the error console outputs this:

```
[Crashlytics] Version 3.1.0 (65)
[Crashlytics:Crash] Reporting is disabled
[Crashlytics] Crash reporting could not be initialized
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Mike, can you take a look at the output for you debug mode when you cause a crash: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/fabric/advanced-settings/debugging.html

Also, it's important to note crashes in the simulator are only reported if you press the stop button in Xcode and relaunch the app in stand-alone (attached to debugger is fine) mode. Thanks!

Comment: Added above in my comments thanks. Btw i'm using visual studio not Xcode.

Comment: Thanks Mike. If the app is not showing in your dashboard you will need to add the app in Xcode. You can do this with your actual app or any app with the same bundle ID. After that you'll potentially be able to get up and running. 

However, you output looks like there may be an additional issue. We don't officially support Xamarin but there are some bindings on Github that may help.